ALV Grid doesn't check for cross-structure foreign keys
I have an editable ALV Grid. The line type consists of two include types, both defined in the DDIC. A field from one structure has a foreign key in the other.
When I edit that field in the ALV, the foreign key from the other structure is not checked by the standard routines.
The fieldcat references the DDIC structures (in fields ref_table and ref_field)
Method CL_GUI_ALV_GRID=>foreign_key_check() fails to find the value of the foreign key because lp_ref_table->* only contains the structure of the modified field and not the entire line.
Is this a bug or is there a special way to make sure the ALV Grid check for foreign keys ?

The two or more fields of the foreign key should refer to the same DDIC object. It's how F4 works in the Dynpro technology, and what ALV Grid implements.
So, not a bug.
If needed, create your own DDIC structure with the foreign keys, and fill REF_TABLE with the name of this DDIC structure.
Minimal code to reproduce:
REPORT z_demo.
DATA go_alv   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.
DATA gt_sbook TYPE TABLE OF sbook.

PARAMETERS dummy.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF go_alv IS NOT BOUND.
    go_alv = NEW #( i_parent = cl_gui_container=>screen0 ).
    SELECT * FROM sbook UP TO 10 ROWS INTO TABLE gt_sbook.
    go_alv->set_table_for_first_display( EXPORTING i_structure_name = 'SBOOK'
                                                   is_layout        = VALUE #( edit = 'X' )
                                         CHANGING  it_outtab        = gt_sbook ).
  ENDIF.

SBOOK has these foreign keys:
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.label : 'Prüfung gegen Flugverbindung'
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.screenCheck : true
  key connid : s_conn_id not null
    with foreign key spfli
      where mandt = sbook.mandt
        and carrid = sbook.carrid
        and connid = sbook.connid;
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.label : 'Prüfung gegen Flugtabelle'
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.keyType : #KEY
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.screenCheck : true
  key fldate : s_date not null
    with foreign key [0..*,1] sflight
      where mandt = sbook.mandt
        and carrid = sbook.carrid
        and connid = sbook.connid
        and fldate = sbook.fldate;

Example: enter 23 in the CONNID field, it gets AA from the CARRID field, and issues the adequate error:


Thank you ! I've copied the standard routine into the handler of event data_changed and adapted it a bit.

I've copied a part of the standard routine from CL_GUI_ALV_GRID=>foreign_key_check( ) into the handler of event data_changed and adapted it a bit to check for cross-structure foreign keys.
METHOD handle_data_changed.
    DATA: msg                  type sy,
          lt_dd05m             TYPE TABLE OF dd05m,
          ls_dd05m             TYPE dd05m,
          lt_dd08v             TYPE TABLE OF dd08v,
          ls_dd08v             TYPE dd08v,
          lt_dd03p             TYPE TABLE OF dd03p,
          ls_dd03p             TYPE dd03p,
          lt_additional_fields TYPE dcfielddats,
          ls_additional_fields TYPE dcfielddat,
          lr_additional_value  TYPE REF TO data.

    data(lt_fieldcat) = sender->get_frontend_fieldcatalog( ).
    LOOP AT er_data_changed->mt_good_cells into data(ls_good_cell).
        read table lt_fieldcat with key fieldname = ls_good_cell-fieldname into data(ls_fieldcat_entry).

        CALL FUNCTION 'DD_TBFK_GET'
          EXPORTING
            tabl_name   = ls_fieldcat_entry-ref_table
            fieldname   = ls_fieldcat_entry-ref_field
            get_state   = 'A'
          TABLES
            dd05m_tab_a = lt_dd05m
            dd08v_tab_a = lt_dd08v.
          .
        DELETE lt_dd05m WHERE fortable = '*'.

        CLEAR lt_additional_fields.

        LOOP AT lt_dd05m INTO ls_dd05m
                WHERE fieldname EQ ls_fieldcat_entry-ref_field
                  AND forkey    NE ls_fieldcat_entry-ref_field.
          ls_additional_fields-tabname   = ls_dd05m-fortable.
          ls_additional_fields-fieldname = ls_dd05m-forkey.
          ls_additional_fields-found = 'X'.
          READ TABLE lt_fieldcat INTO data(ls_forkey_fieldcat)
                     WITH KEY ref_table = ls_dd05m-fortable
                              ref_field = ls_dd05m-forkey.
          IF sy-subrc EQ 0.

            ASSIGN COMPONENT ls_forkey_fieldcat-fieldname
                             OF STRUCTURE er_data_changed->mp_mod_rows[ ls_good_cell-tabix ] TO field-symbol(<l_field>).
            IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
              GET REFERENCE OF <l_field> INTO lr_additional_value.
              ls_additional_fields-value     = lr_additional_value.
              INSERT ls_additional_fields
                   INTO TABLE lt_additional_fields.
            ENDIF.
          ENDIF.
        ENDLOOP.

        CALL FUNCTION 'DDUT_INPUT_CHECK'
          EXPORTING
            tabname            = ls_fieldcat_entry-ref_table
            fieldname          = conv fnam_____4( ls_fieldcat_entry-ref_field )
            value              = iv_value
            value_is_external  = abap_true
          IMPORTING
            msgid              = msg-msgid
            msgty              = msg-msgty
            msgno              = msg-msgno
            msgv1              = msg-msgv1
            msgv2              = msg-msgv2
            msgv3              = msg-msgv3
            msgv4              = msg-msgv4
          CHANGING
            additional_fields  = lt_additional_fields
          EXCEPTIONS
            no_ddic_field      = 1
            illegal_move       = 2
            others             = 3
          .
        IF sy-subrc <> 0 OR msg-msgty = 'E'.
            " Handle error here
        ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
ENDMETHOD.

